# Overlay Live video with paintbrush style drawings?

Tags: opencv, video, tkinter, overlay

I need some direction on whats the best programming approach to overlay a live video from a webcam (or a pre loaded video), with paintbrush. i.e, drawing lines , circles and such, to mark areas in the video while its playing.

right now using OpenCV + Tkinter, is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks

EDIT: trying to paint directly on the video window, but cant get it to work.. here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
def interactive_drawing(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing, mode

    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing=True
        ix,iy=x,y

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing==True:
            if mode==True:
                cv2.line(frame,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,0,255),10)
                ix=x
                iy=y
                print x,y
    elif event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing=False
        if mode==True:
            cv2.line(frame,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,0,255),10)
            ix=x
            iy=y
    return x,y

drawing=False # true if mouse is pressed
mode=True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('track.avi')


while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        break
 #   cv2.namedWindow("frame", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
 #   cv2.setWindowProperty("frame",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.setMouseCallback('frame',interactive_drawing)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(15) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()



# mouse callback function






##img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
##
##cv2.namedWindow('begueradj')
##cv2.setMouseCallback('begueradj',interactive_drawing)
##while(1):
##    cv2.imshow('begueradje',img)
##    k=cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF
##    if k==27:
##        break
##cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only use **OpenCV** for that purpose, as it already provides [drawing functions](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) such as :

- Lines
- Rectangles
- Circles
- Ellipses
- Polygons
- etc.

**EDIT**: This code snippet should help you get started. The important point here is that you have to save the drawing elements in a variable (`curve_points` in my case) and draw them on each new frames:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
def interactive_drawing(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global drawing, mode

    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing=True

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing==True:
            if mode==True:
                curves[len(curves)-1].append((x,y)) #append new points to the last list of curves

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing=False
        if mode==True:
            curves.append([]) #adding a new list to curves

    return x,y

def draw_curves(myArray):

    for j in range(0, len(myArray)):
        for i in range(1, len(myArray[j])):
            cv2.line(frame,myArray[j][i-1],myArray[j][i],(0,0,255),10)

drawing=False # true if mouse is pressed
mode=True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #cap = cv2.VideoCapture('track.avi')
curves = [[]] # initializing curves list with an empty list
cv2.namedWindow('frame')
cv2.setMouseCallback('frame',interactive_drawing)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        break
    draw_curves(curves)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(15) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks Laine, from what i found online, It is ineed poissble with openCV to draw on an empty window, paintbrush style. what I need to some reference to a code that does that on a video window. for example somhow to modify this code to work on a video window. (added code in my answer)

Comment: @David I am setting up a python environment to be able to test your code out and hopefully find a fix.

Comment: Laine, Thats great! almost exactly what  i needed, the only thing needs changing is , right now, when you finish drawing a curve , move the mouse to a new location and draw again, the code connects the last poistion of the mouse in the old curve to the new position, so if you try to draw a simple line in right and left sides for example, they will be connected. need each curve to be seperated from one another (obviously the seperation starts when left keymouse is unpressed after finishing drawing a curve).  i'll try to figure it  tonight!

Comment: @David Yes, indeed. To address this problem, you could do something like: On `EVENT_LBUTTONUP` event, append the content of `curve_points` into another array (that you could call `curves`). Then you would nest the existing `for` loop (in `draw_curves()`) into another `for` loop that iterates over the `curves` elements. If my answer helped you, consider accepting it ;)

Comment: Yep that seems like a goid idea. Ill try it when i get home from work and let you know what I come up with. Marked u as answer. Thx!

Comment: Laine, having some trouble getting it to work. I have added a mouse event , appending the new points to curve_points2 upon mouse button up, but while iterating over the curve function loop, it still behaves the same, I probably dont know how to do the nesting of the for loops. want to give it a shot if you have time? THX

Comment: @David It's your lucky day! I updated my code snippet with the **nested** `for` loops. I also did a bit of refactoring to be able to see in real-time the currently drawn curve.

Comment: awesome implementation Laine, That was the reason I got so much trouble with it, I could make it draw the curves AFTER i finish drawing with the mouse. couldn't see it in real time. your changes are great, I also added a simple delete all drawings once right mouse clicked. greatly appreciate your help mate, u'r a good man (and coder) A++